# A* Generic Implementation in Swift

Tags: swift, a-star

My first Code Review post.

I'm up to a [generic implementation of the A* search algorithm in Swift](https://github.com/adelredjimmy/Swift-Generic-A-Star) (for now, it's a single goal implementation).

Here's what's been coded so far:

```
// State : a protocole for states in the search space
protocol State : Equatable {

    // successors() : returns an array of successors states in the search space
    func successors() -> [Successor<Self>]

    // heuristic(goal) : returns the heuristic value for a given states in relation to a given goal state
    func heuristic(goal:Self) -> Double

    // id : a string identifying a state
    var id : String { get }

}

// States are compared by their id
func ==<T:State>(lhs:T, rhs:T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id==rhs.id
}

// Successor : represents a successor state and its cost
struct Successor<T:State> {
    var state: T
    var cost: Double
}

// Plan : a plan of states
struct Plan<T:State> {

    // states : an array of states that make a plan
    var states: [T]

    // cost : the total cost of the plan
    var cost: Double

    // isNot(another) : checks if another plan is different from the current one
    func isNot(another: Plan) -> Bool {
        return !(states == another.states && cost == another.cost)
    }

}

// AStar<TState> : finds the A* solution (nil if no solution found) given a start state and goal state
func AStar<TState:State>(start: TState, goal: TState) -> Plan<TState>? {

    var fringe : [Plan<TState>] = [Plan(states: [start], cost: 0)]

    while fringe.count>0 {

        let bestPlan = fringe.minElement({
            a,b
            in
            a.cost + a.states.last!.heuristic(goal) < b.cost + b.states.last!.heuristic(goal)
        })!

        fringe = fringe.filter({
            plan in plan.isNot(bestPlan)
        })

        if bestPlan.states.last! == goal {
            return bestPlan
        }else{
            let successors = bestPlan.states.last!.successors()
            for successor in successors.filter({ s in !bestPlan.states.contains(s.state) }) {
                let newPlan = Plan(states: bestPlan.states+[successor.state], cost: bestPlan.cost+successor.cost)
                fringe.append(newPlan)
            }
        }

    }

    return nil

}
```

I'm here for some suggestions to make this Swiftier

EDIT:

I tested this implementation using a graph of vertices representing cities with costs representing road distances. I used the straight line distance as a heuristic value :

```
let adjacencyList : [String:[String:Double]] = [
    "oued"      :   ["biskra":150.0],
    "biskra"    :   ["batna":120.0, "oued":150.0],
    "batna"     :   ["biskra":120.0, "barika":40.0, "setif":100.0, "constantine":110.0],
    "barika"    :   ["batna":40.0, "setif":50.0],
    "setif"     :   ["batna":100.0, "barika":50.0, "constantine":50.0, "bejaia":80.0],
    "constantine":  ["batna":110.0, "setif":50.0, "annaba":80.0],
    "bajaia"    :   ["setif":80.0, "annaba":30.0],
    "annaba"    :   ["constantine":80.0, "bejaia":30.0]
]

let straightLineDistances = [
    "biskra"    :   ["annaba":220.0],
    "batna"     :   ["annaba":140.0],
    "barika"    :   ["annaba":200.0],
    "setif"     :   ["annaba":100.0],
    "constantine":  ["annaba":80.0],
    "bejaia"    :   ["annaba":30.0],
    "oued"      :   ["annaba":320.0],
    "annaba"    :   ["annaba":0.0]
]


final class Vertex : State, CustomDebugStringConvertible {

    let label : String

    init(label:String) {
        self.label = label
    }

    func successors() -> [Successor<Vertex>] {
        return adjacencyList[label]!.map { x in Successor<Vertex>(state:Vertex(label: x.0),cost: x.1) }
    }

    func heuristic(goal:Vertex) -> Double {
        return straightLineDistances[label]![goal.label]!
    }

    var id : String {
        return label
    }

    var debugDescription : String {
        return id
    }

}

let solution = AStar(Vertex(label: "biskra"), goal: Vertex(label: "annaba"))

print(solution)
```

And the output solutions was the expected A* solution. But I'm more concerned about the elegance of this implementation

Comment: Is there any chance that you add a (small) example to your project where your A* algorithm is used with concrete data? That would make it simpler to try your code and possible improvements.

Comment: Example added @MartinR

Comment: This does not look like the plain A* algorithm, but also looks different (to me) from the "Fringe search" (as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fringe_search). So which algorithm did you implement here? (Sorry if that should be a dumb question, I am not an expert on this topic.)

Comment: From [where I learned A*](https://courses.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS188x_1/1T2013/info) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), this is the basic A* search algorithm.
What I called `fringe`is also called the `open set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code isn't bad at all. You make great use of the generic features of Swift and you also go for the functional approach over the iterative one whenever it's a good fit. Here are some ways to make your code "Swiftier":

1. **Spacing.** Readability is very important in Swift and your code currently doesn't follow all the best practices. Operators are usually surrounded by spaces (e.g. `lhs.id == rhs.id`) and colons are usually only followed by a space (e.g. `protocol State: Equatable` and `var id: String`).
2. **Don't force unwrap.** You used `states.last!` twice. Even though `states` is never empty in this case, the compiler doesn't actually enforce it. No matter how sure you are that a value isn't `nil`, it's generally frowned upon to use `!`. Instead, you could add `var lastState: T` to the `Plan` struct which keeps track of the last state.
3. **Use trailing closures.** If the last parameter of a function is a closure, you can put it outside the brackets: `myArray.filter { $0 > 3 }`.
4. The `isNot(_:)` function is not very Swifty. Using `!=` would make much more sense, so the logical thing to do is to extend `Plan` to conform to `Equatable`. Also, I don't think you have to check whether `cost == another.cost` because there's no way the two would be different if the states are equal.
5. Don't use `fringe.count > 0`, but instead use `!fringe.isEmpty`. It's both more readable and for some data structures it's also more efficient (in case there's no constant time random access).
6. Instead of force unwrapping `minElement`, use `while let bestPlan = fringe.minElement(...)` instead.
7. Don't use short closure arguments such as `a`, `b`, `x`. Either give them more meaningful names, or use anonymous closure arguments (`$0`, `$1`, etc.).
8. Instead of using `filter` to remove `bestPlan` from `fringe`, use `removeAtIndex` instead. You can get this index using `fringe.indexOf(bestPlan)` (which you can unwrap simultaneously with `fringe`).
9. Use a `guard` to return `bestPlan` in case the goal is reached, both to increase readability and to prevent nesting.
10. Use a `where`-clause instead of `filter` to loop through all successors that are not contained in `bestPlan.states`. Using `filter` is good, but this is what `where` is for.
11. The way you construct `newPlan` isn't very elegant. You could consider adding an `append` function to `Plan` for adding a successor.

Here's what my version looks like after the changes:

```
// State : a protocole for states in the search space
protocol State: Equatable {

    // successors() : returns an array of successors states in the search space
    func successors() -> [Successor<Self>]

    // heuristic(goal) : returns the heuristic value in relation to a given goal state
    func heuristic(goal: Self) -> Double

    // id : a string identifying a state
    var id: String { get }

}

// States are compared by their id
func == <T: State> (lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

// Successor : represents a successor state and its cost
struct Successor<T: State> {
    var state: T
    var cost: Double
}

// Plan : a plan of states
struct Plan<T: State> {

    // states : an array of states that make a plan
    var states: [T]

    // lastState : the last state of the plan
    var lastState: T

    // cost : the total cost of the plan
    var cost: Double

    // initialise a plan with a single state
    init(state: T) {
        states = [state]
        lastState = state
        cost = 0
    }

    // append a successor to this plan
    mutating func append(successor: Successor<T>) {
        states.append(successor.state)
        lastState = successor.state
        cost += successor.cost
    }

    // the non-mutating version of append(_:)
    func appending(successor: Successor<T>) -> Plan {
        var new = self
        new.append(successor)
        return new
    }

}

extension Plan: Equatable {}

func == <T: State> (lhs: Plan<T>, rhs: Plan<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.states == rhs.states
}

// AStar<TState> : finds the A* solution (nil if no solution found) given a start state and goal state
func AStar <TState: State> (start: TState, goal: TState) -> Plan<TState>? {

    var fringe = [Plan(state: start)]

    // computes the best plan from the fringe array
    // I made this its own function to make the `while let` statement more readable
    func bestPlan() -> Plan<TState>? {
        return fringe.minElement {
            $0.cost + $0.lastState.heuristic(goal) < $1.cost + $1.lastState.heuristic(goal)
        }
    }

    while let bestPlan = bestPlan(), index = fringe.indexOf(bestPlan) {
        fringe.removeAtIndex(index)

        guard bestPlan.lastState != goal else { return bestPlan }

        let successors = bestPlan.lastState.successors()

        for successor in successors where !bestPlan.states.contains(successor.state) {
            fringe.append(bestPlan.appending(successor))
        }
    }

    return nil

}
```

Comment: What about `lastState` as a computed property?

Comment: You could, but then you still need `!`... An alternative would be to let `Plan` have `let firstState: T` and `var successorStates: [T]` as properties. This ensures that there's always at least one state (`firstState`). Then adding a `lastState` computed property would make sense: `var lastState: T { return successorStates.last ?? firstState }`

Comment: This is a nice review: as a new Swift learner (version 5) I found it informative. There are 2 or 3 syntax errors and 3 or 5 code errors from deprecated swift code that I was able fix and then it compiled and ran.  It worked using either of the first two nodes but failed for the others.